# How pthread_join() determine that called/waiting thread is terminated

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

i am new in Multithreading. in pthread_join() function we put the main thread on wait till the called thread is not terminated. So my question is here how pthread_join() verify that called thread is terminated.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the main thread". All threads are equal. `pthread_join` joins the target thread with the *calling* thread.

Comment: A thread is controlled via a structure. Thread termination is an *event* catched by the thread scheduling system which then look if some other thread is *joining* on this one. If it is the case, it will be waked up.

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_join` is a portable interface around an operating system facility that instructs the OS scheduler to suspend the calling thread until the target thread has communicated that it has completed (either by returning from its entry point function or because `pthread_exit` has been called). The necessary wrapping logic and state set up by `pthread_create`. Essentially, you are  waiting for a flag to change, but that's all handled for you by the pthreads library.